# Pandas: unexpectedly output data type using python map()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I am using `map()` on pandas.Dataframe.
I am trying to map string to some specific integer.

```
>>> df_train['gold_label'].head()
0          neutral
1    contradiction
2       entailment
3    contradiction
4    contradiction
Name: gold_label, dtype: object
>>> dic = {'entailment': 0, 'neutral': 1, 'contradiction': 2}
>>> df_train['gold_label'] = df_train['gold_label'].map(dic)
>>> df_train['gold_label'].head()
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    0.0
3    2.0
4    2.0
Name: gold_label, dtype: float64
```

I am expecting to get a integer result but actually a `float64`.
However, i use another the same format dataset(above is dev dataset), the result will be integer as expected.

Where goes wrong in above procedures?

Comment: your column might be having Null values.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Akshay, if there is a value outside of the dictionary mapping found in the dataframe the resulting value will be 'NaN' and lead to the float64 result.

```
> a
array(['neutral', 'contradiction', 'entailment', 'contradiction',
   'contradiction'],
  dtype='|S13')
> b
array(['neutral', 'contradiction', 'entailment', 'contradiction',
   'contradiction', 'test'],
  dtype='|S13')
> d = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['gold_label'])
> d2 = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['gold_label'])
> dic = {'contradiction': 2, 'entailment': 0, 'neutral': 1}
> d['gold_label'].map(dic)
 0    1
 1    2
 2    0
 3    2
 4    2
 Name: gold_label, dtype: int64
 > d2['gold_label'].map(dic)
 0    1.0
 1    2.0
 2    0.0
 3    2.0
 4    2.0
 5    NaN
 Name: gold_label, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! That is the reason. I found null value in dataset. I trust the data source but i should always do data exploration before going further!